# Where to get my own Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP)

Tags: research, ux-field

Is there any (software) framework or company that offers "Customer Experience Improvement Program" (CEIP) like Microsoft uses it?

I think this should enable software vendors to do thinks like that:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2009/11/03/data-driven-engineering-tracking-usage-to-make-decisions.aspx

Comment: CEIP is a very expensive and complicated undertaking since it requires not only collection of large amounts of data but also anonymizing, storing, and analyzing it.

Comment: Agree. Thats exactly what I need. But where to get it without reinventing it all?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Gibraltar, like Kevin says. Also you can use [SAS](http://sas.com/solutions/crm/customer-experience/index.html). I recommend you to read this article in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_intelligence).

What you need is called Runtime Intelligence. It's a mixed of two disciplines: business intelligence (BI) and Software Development Life Cycle (SDLC). Gibraltar is one of this kind of software.

Also you can use: Trackerbird Software Analytics; Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Dotfuscator Community Edition; Software Statistics Service.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Deskmetrics](http://deskmetrics.com) is an awesome tool for creating CEIP's. 
It is a web-based analytics platform (like Google Analytics for desktop software) that helps developers and companies understand how their desktop software is being used. It's a great way to increase software quality, and identify improvement opportunities. I strongly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

[Gibraltar](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/See/Customer-Experience-Improvement-Program.aspx) is a good option if your software is written in .NET.